# data-custom-toggle on click, not on enter

Tags: javascript, css

I have this search element that has different fields and also this `#goal` div. At the bottom on the form/element there are 2 buttons `MORE` and `SEARCH`. The target is when a user clicks `MORE` to toggle the class   and show the content of the `#goal` and in the same time if `ENTER` is pressed then the `SEARCH` should be clicked and the form submitted.

The HTML:

```
....
<div id="goal" class="well-toggle offset-top-10">
....    
</div>

<div class="offset-top-10">
    <button data-custom-toggle="#goal" class="btn btn-block btn-white" id="bntMore">
        MORE BTN
    </button>
</div>

<div class="offset-top-10">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-white" id="btnSearch">SEARCH</button>
</div>
...
```

this is the javascript:

```
$this.on('click', $.proxy(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $ctx = $(this);
    $($ctx.attr('data-custom-toggle')).add(this).toggleClass('active');

    setTimeout(function () {
      $window.trigger('resize');
    }, 1000);

  }, $this));
```

If anyone has a suggestion or a tip how to do this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your main objective is for the form to submit when the user presses ENTER? Is this markup wrapped in `<form>` tags?

Comment: Yes, it is wrapped in a form. That is the objective and in the same time when a mouse click on more, then unfold the #goal div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to replace the first  tag with a span. CSS is the same, but when enter is pressed then the second button tag is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onclick, see example:

```
<button data-custom-toggle="#goal" class="btn btn-block btn-white" onclick="clickFunction(this)" id="bntMore">
   MORE BTN
</button>
<script>
        var clickFunction = function(elem) {
            event.preventdefault();
            var customToggle = elem.getAttribute('data-custom-toggle');
            $(customToggle).add(elem).toggleClass('active');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(window).trigger('resize');
            }, 1000);
        }
</script>
```

if you prefer to follow the way you initially created:

```
<script>
    $("[data-custom-toggle]").click(function(){
            event.preventdefault();
            var customToggle = this.getAttribute('data-custom-toggle');
            $(customToggle).add(this).toggleClass('active');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(window).trigger('resize');
            }, 1000);
        });
</script>
```

or, if nothing works:

```
       $("[data-custom-toggle]").click(function(){
            clickFunction(this);
            event.preventdefault();
        });

        $("[data-custom-toggle]").keydown(function(event){
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                clickFunction(this);
                event.preventdefault();
            }
        });

        var clickFunction = function(elem) {

            var customToggle = elem.getAttribute('data-custom-toggle');
            $(customToggle).add(elem).toggleClass('active');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(window).trigger('resize');
            }, 1000);
        }
```